# How to split message into multiple fields logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to split a field with a full log line in multiple fields (instead of one field). Right now the log values are separated with pipelines, and want to know if there is a way to do it. Thanks in advance.

A log line example:

```
INFO |2017-12-06T15:00:00,344|532fdcaa-ca27-4b38-8d6b-408bd72e94f2|qk29fnkgsye45d33hxsuctdu:AMOMA|ApiAvailabilityRQ|0||20171208|20171111|1~2~0|HTL:true,COMPANYNAME>121704;PAY:AT_WEB|ADC68E2C0F1D4FF08F6D6DBCCCB227011600|1|4
```

My grok:

```
grok {
    match => [ "message", "^(?m)%{WORD:level}\s?\|%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\|(?<echoToken>([^|]*))\|(?<apiKey>(\w*))(\:(?<ttoo>([\w ]*)))?\|%{WORD:operation}\|%{NUMBER:processTime}\|((?<exceptionType>[^|\:]+)(\:(?<exceptionDetail>[^|#]+)(###(?<exceptionMessage>[^|]+))?)?)?\|(((?<checkin>(\d+))\|(?<checkout>(\d+))\|(?<occupancy>([\d~#]+))\|((?:HTL:)(?<hotels_included(true|false)),(?:HOTELBEDS|GIATA)\->(?<hotels>([\d|,]+))|(?:DST:(?<destination>(\w+))(\w*))(;ZON:(?<zone>(\d+)))?|(GEO:(?<geo>([^;]*))))(;(?<filters>[^|]+))?\|(?<cacheKey>(\w+))?\|(?<num_hotels>(\d+))\|(?<num_ratekeys>(\d+))(\|(?<slow>(SLOW)))?)|((?<bookingDetail>(\d+-\d+))(\|(?<checkin>(\d+))\|(?<checkout>(\d+))\|(?<hotel>(\d+))\|(?<destination>(\w+))\|(?<zone>(\d+))\|(?<amount>([\d\.]+))\|%{GREEDYDATA:rateKey})?)|%{GREEDYDATA:logMessage})" ]
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add an example of the log you want to parse and what field you want to retrieve.

Comment: Of course. It´s done :)

Comment: Well the end of the grok pattern is completely wrong, beginning at `((?<checkin>(\d+))`. It should have been easier to split the regex in multiple pattern instead of putting everything in the same regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern managed to grab the values separated by pipes.

```
^(?m)%{WORD:level}\s?\|%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\|(?<echoToken>([^|]*))\|(?<apiKey>(\w*))(\:(?<ttoo>([\w ]*)))?\|%{WORD:operation}\|%{NUMBER:processTime}\|((?<exceptionType>[^|\:]+)(\:(?<exceptionDetail>[^|#]+)(###(?<exceptionMessage>[^|]+))?)?)?\|%{NUMBER:A}\|%{NUMBER:B}\|%{DATA:C}\|%{DATA:D}\|%{DATA:E}\|%{NUMBER:F}\|%{NUMBER:G}
```

The beginning is based on the one provided in the question, with the ending made to grab the content between the pipes.